# Check if user_picture value is changed or compare with old value

Tags: 8, forms

I am trying to find if a field value is changed or updated by the user. But there are blockers.

```
function custom_form_process_user_picture(&$form, FormStateInterface &$form_state) {
  $file_name = "";
  $username = "";
  $fid_0 = NULL;
  $user_picture = $form['user_picture'];
  $uid = $form_state->getValue('uid');
  if ($form_state->hasFileElement() && $form_state->hasValue('user_picture')) {
    $username = $form_state->getValue('field_name')[0]['value'];
    $fid_0 = isset($form_state->getValue('user_picture')[0]['fids'][0]) ? $form_state->getValue('user_picture')[0]['fids'][0] : $fid_0;
    /*
      $changed = $form_state->get('user_picture')->getValue() == $form_state->getValue('user_picture');
      //This is not working as $form_state->get() returns null.
    */
    /*
      $changed = $form_state->get('user_picture')->getValue() == $form['user_picture']['#default_value'];
      //This is not working as $form['user_picture']['#default_value'] is null.
    */
      if($changed) {
        // Proceed to rename the file.
      }
    }
```

What piece of the code I am doing wrong? Searched drupal and stackoverflow for the changed/updated/dirty field value. Also tried with `$form_state->getFormObject()->getEntity()` and got no clue if there is old value stored or not.
`FormStateInterface` seems to have no method to find out altered/modified values.

Comment: Can you explain a little what you are trying to accomplish?  This hook may not be the right place to do what you need.

Comment: I want to change the file name but when edit the form value gets replaced. I am using `MYMODULE_form_alter` and this is `$form['#validate']` method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you should use `hook_entity_presave` that keeps the old (original) value

```
function MODULENAME_entity_presave(Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityInterface $entity) {

  if($entity->getEntityTypeId() == "file"){

    $filename = $entity->getFilename();

    $file_old = $entity->original;

    if($file_old != null){
      $filename_old = $file_old->getFilename();

      if($filename_old !== $filename){
        $entity->setFilename('newfile.jpg');
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The function above changes the filename if its not the same as old filename.

Depending on your use case you might want to apply the above logic when `user` is presaved

```
function MODULENAME_entity_presave(Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityInterface $entity)
  if($entity->getEntityTypeId() == "user"){

    // get specific field by field machine name
    $file = $entity->get('field_file');

    // or get the user_picture field
    $picture = $entity->get('user_picture');

    $user_old = $entity->original;
    // drill down in the old user object to see values changes
    // and do appropriate changes
  }
}
```

Comment: Can I not replace _`entity`_ with `file` or `image`??? `MYMODULE_image_presave` or `MYMODULE_file_presave` hooks are not triggering. I updated drupal, db, files and version.

Comment: `MYMODULE_file_presave` should fire but on my code I am actually checking whether the entity is a file (if statement).  I have added some more details in the answer.   image is actually a file with restrictions ;-)

Comment: Thanks, is am doing `MODULENAME_entity_presave` works somehow. And it's the better way to achieve this. I was doing it all wrong.